# Entity Framework 6 Migrations - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

Currently Visual Studio 2015 CTP6 (as of this question) does not support migrations for Entity Framework 6.  They currently do a workaround to get the login stuff working.  My question is - is support for migrations for entity framework 6 coming or given that EF7 migrations will be done differently, is support being dropped for EF6 migrations.

If there is a plan, does anyone know when it might be coming?

Comment: If Microsoft is going to use stackoverflow as their "forum" then questions like this are completely valid questions so not sure why the down vote.  There is no documentation stating that it will support and nothing on the [timeline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/03/26/visual-studio-upcoming-features-timeline.aspx)  that states it will be coming.

Comment: Microsoft only suggests the use of stackoverflow for programming related matters. For questions like this, the actual Microsoft forum is http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home reached using Visual Studio's own website/support.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, EF6 will be supported for a long time, even after EF7 has been released.

The reason is that EF6 will be the last version to support ObjectContext and many of the legacy features that a lot of older code might still depend on, so this branch will have to be maintained for some time to come.

EF7, on the other hand, will still be considered sort of "beta" when released in Version 7, and incomplete.  So EF6 will still be the featureful branch probably until at least 7.1 or later.

So my guess is that a new version of EF6 will be released that supports VS2015.  But I have no inside knowledge about this, just a guess.